# Relaying mail for a machine with port 25 blocked

Tags: smtp, email-server, exim

I recently moved and had to start using a new residential ISP (my old one doesn't serve the new address yet). To my dismay, the new ISP has no option of unblocking the TCP/25 port even when you buy a static IP address, so my home server currently has no inbound/outbound email capability.

Assuming I can install a Raspberry Pi box at work where no ports are filtered, how could I proceed with working around this issue? Tunneling all my traffic through VPN is an overkill, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managing your own mail server is a more complicated task than running the tunnel between your work and home servers.
Here is the explanation from DigitalOcean why you should think twice before setting up your own mail server:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/why-you-may-not-want-to-run-your-own-mail-server

Comment: Read that link and do think twice about this plan.  If the mail server gets exploited for spam, your employer is going to get blacklisted.  Depending on where you work and how well you documented their consent (you *are* planning to get written consent, right?) you may also be charged with and convicted of a felony.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the advice. While the technical solution of setting up a smarthost sounds like a fun exercise, I spent less then half an hour to set up everything I needed (inbound/outbound email + forwarding to GMail) with mailgun.com. They're really good so far, set them up as my smarthost - works like a charm. Fortunately, TCP/587 isn't blocked by my ISP.

Answer (score -1):

My answer was ... How about other ports?  There is a chance that if you require encryption on your server, you can work around using port 25.